# How to solve this minimization problem in classical mechanics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, constrained-dynamics

One should minimize the distance between two points **x1**=(x1,y1) and **x2**=(x2,y2). The holonomic constraint states that $f(x)=x^2-2x+5$ where **x1** is an element of this graph and **x2** is an element of the graph of a different function: $g(x)=2x-1$.
Now the goal is to use the constraints in such a way, to eliminate two of the given coordinates x1,x2,y1,y2. After the elimination one should determine the minimum of the distance between these  2 points.
A hint is that this process is reminiscent of the 2. Lagrangian formalism.

I just don't even know where to start off, I would be so grateful if someone could help me out somehow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to give two hints to the problem and leave the calculation and interpretation on to you.

The first one is a little more from geometry. Look at the graph of the [curves](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iqhomp2uaa) :

[image]

Now If you look at it carefully it's rather obvious that the distance between such points will be minimum if the second line will be parallel to the tangent of the red curve. Thus, find out the slope of the red curve and equate it to the slope of the blue line. And this will lead you to the coordinates of the points.

---

The second is more general on defining a distance function or rather distance square function as
$$\phi=(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2$$

Use the fact that you know what $y_1$ and $y_2$ is in term of others. So
$$\phi=f(x_1,x_2)$$

Now you know how to find the minimum of such functions.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot!